# %u format Specifier in C

Tags: c

I compiled this code and it gave the the value of '&x' 3 times. That is if &x = 2000 it printed 2036 three times. I want to know the reason for this behaviour assuming an integer requires 4 bytes of memory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    int x[4][3] = {0};
    printf("%u %u %u", x+3, *(x+3), *(x+2)+3);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x is a pointer to an array of pointers. The array of pointers has 4 elements. Each of these four elements points to 3 integers.

Hence if x = 2000 then,

x[0] = 2000, x[1] = 2012, x[2] = 2024, x[3] = 2036.

Therefore,

x + 3 = 2036 (because x is an array pointer and it increases by 12 each time.)

*(x+3) = x[3] = 2036 again.

*(x+2)+3 = x[2] + 3 = 2024 + 3*4 = 2036 again.

Hence the output will be three same numbers.

Answer (score 3):

> What will be the output of this code

Anything can happen as the code provokes undefined behaviour by printing a pointer value using the conversion specifier for an `unsigned`.

To print pointer values use the conversion specifier `p`.

---

The address of an array and the address of its 1st element are the same. Pointers to them both however are of different type.

---

`x` as well as `x + 3` are of type `int (*)[3]`, that is pointing to an array of three `int`s. Assuming `int` to be of size `4`, an array of three `int`s is of size `12`.

Increasing `x` (a pointer to `int (*)[3]`) by three elements one ends up with an address `3 * 12` bytes beyond where `x` points to. This is called pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @Rame: You not only "*could*" use `p`, but you should, as undefined behaviour is undefined.

Comment: This question was asked in a competitive exam. Hence it has to be answered. The behaviour is not undefined. I found an explanation to the output :)

Comment: @Rama; Interesting! How could you be so sure that it's not undefined behavior? Please let us know.

Comment: C11Standard (draft) 7.21.6.1/9: "*... If any argument is
not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
undefined.*" @Rama

Comment: @rama according to the C11 standard it **is** undefined behaviour, the guy who wrote the question got it wrong. On the other hand on most 32 bit systems (or even 16bit systems) %u would just print the address in decimal, even if it is technically UB.

Comment: The behavior maybe undefined according to the standard, I accept. But the output on any compiler is three identical values corresponding to the address of x. The output is different in each run, but in one run we get three same values. Probably that is the concept the one who framed the question wanted to test. You cannot say he was wrong :)

Comment: Printing a segmented address (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation) most probably would fail, if not crash the program. @Rama

Answer (score 1):

You're misusing a format specifier and invoking undefined behavior because of that. At that point, what happens is arbitrary and uninteresting.

If you want to print a pointer, use the `%p` specifier.

Comment: Actually the point here is not the wrong format specifier, the question would be the same if he had used `%p` instead of `%u`. And on most 32bit systems (or even 16bit systems) %u would just print the address in decimal even if technically it is UB.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: I agree. However the question's title is definitely pushing to focus on the formal fact of UB ... :-/

Comment: @MichaelWalz Yes, but most systems aren't all systems. Its very important for OP to realise what UB is and why he needs to not have it.